# how to parsing with jsoup using asynctask

Tags: java, android, parsing, android-asynctask, jsoup

I have to parse a web page and store the content of some tag in a ListView. 
Now, I have this code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    private MyTask myTask;
    ListView listView;
    final String URL = "http://en.wikipedia.org";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        myTask = new MyTask();
        myTask.execute(URL);
    }

    class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = params[0];
            Document doc;
            Elements table = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                table = doc.select("table").select("tbody");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return table.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.riga);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

but the execution return always a white screen. What can I do?? 
I'm sure that the error is in the postExecute method but I can't see it.

Comment: Are you sure that this `table = doc.select("table").select("tbody");` returns anything?

Comment: yes parser was tested as java program and return always

Comment: Try logging the result in `onPostExecute`and in `doInBackground`. What works for the desktop doesn't necessarily work for the mobile device. Check `userAgent`.